# Communicating with a Java RMI server in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, rmi

Is there any way to build a client on iPhone that is able to communicate with a Java RMI server? I have plans to put the app on app store, so it would be good to know if there is any way allowed by apple to do this.

Comment: Please refer to the following post..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205058/interprocess-communication-between-xcode-objective-c-and-java-rmi][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205058/interprocess-communication-between-xcode-objective-c-and-java-rmi