# Interprocess communication between XCode (Objective C) and Java RMI

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, communication, rmi

I have an RMI application that has service implementation and it has a lot of code in it and I do not want to redo the business logic just to support an iPhone app.

Could someone assist me on a best way to access these RMI services using Objective C? Or is there any other way for making this possible, please let me know if this is a terrible question, being a software programmer, I would expect that there would be a way for heterogeneous programs to communicate with each other, so this question comes to me with that assumption.

Comment: See [Communitcationg with a Java RMI server in iOS SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658946/communitcationg-with-a-java-rmi-server-in-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no Java runtime in iOS, nor any support for Java in the SDK, and an Objective-C app can't start up another process on the device (unless it's jailbroken), so there'd be no way for your app to run a JVM. So the only other option I know of (short of rewriting the Java code) would be to make your Java functionality available via web services.

Also, there's no direct way for applications to communicate with each other (or for that matter to even be running in the foreground simultaneously) in iOS.

Comment: That's a good start, good to know, thanks for the information, I could do that, let's say I create a Servlet that communicates with the RMI service and this servlet would provide a response as a json, I should be able to handle the response, sounds good. thanks again.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like it'd be a good approach. JSON is particularly advantageous for iOS apps. If you're targeting iOS 5, the new `JSONSerialization` class automatically converts object graphs consisting of `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, and `NSString` objects into JSON, and vice-versa. And there are a number of open-source Objective-C frameworks that parallel that functionality, so you can you them to supply similar behavior for earlier SDK versions.